# Error after migrating to Androidx. "android.support.constraint.R.styleable.ImageFilterView" is converted to "android.constraintlayout.R"

Tags: android, android-custom-view, androidx

I am upgrading my project to AndroidX. In my custom view 
`android.support.constraint.R.styleable.ImageFilterView` got converted to 
`androidx.constraintlayout.R.styleable.ImageFilterView`

and gives error Package `androidc.constraintlayout.R` does not exist

I tried looking for respective package for `android.support.constraint` in Androidx but to no effect.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ConstraintLayout` itself is located in `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout`.

The style is located at `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.R.styleable.ImageFilterView`, but ConstraintLayout 2 needs to be used:

```
implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta2"
```

Comment: There is something as `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.R.styleable` but cannot find ImageFilterView there. @Tidder

Comment: @SaurabhKataria The style is located at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.R.styleable.ImageFilterView, but you need to use ConstraintLayout 2.0.0: implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta2"

Comment: Ok let me try this.

Comment: @SaurabhKataria You're welcome. Then you may accept my answer.